# mouseover fires multiple times over one span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

Here's a simple jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/cEDj6/

I have one `span` element that I bound `mouseover` to. When I move the mouse horizontally across different lines of text, `mouseover` happens only once. However, when I move between lines of text within the same span element, `mouseover` happens multiple times.

- Is this expected?
- Is there a standard way of preventing this (short of adding logic to consider the last visited element)?

Using Chromium, version 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 13.04 (28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.13.04.1).

Comment: because is inline element, look at it with a background  http://jsfiddle.net/cEDj6/2/  change to `display:block` and issue dissapears

Comment: @charlietfl great point. I don't know why I didn't mention that. This should be the accepted answer if you post it. I think it's also worth mentioning (as you can see in my answer) that the semantically correct element to use is the `<p`> tag which is a block by default.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks - that makes sense. Funny is that, when a border is added, the issue disappears: http://jsfiddle.net/cEDj6/10/. So I guess it's not because it's an inline element per-se, but because the  wrapping it implies makes the breaks as you show in your jsFiddle. Can you please post this as an answer when you get a chance?

Comment: actually I was surprised by the problem...that's what made me think about a background to see what mouse was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to stem from an inline elemnt `<span>` with multiple lines of text. In reality space between each line is not contained in element as far as mouse is concerned.

This can be seen by putting background color on element. Changing it to block elemnt in css with `display:block` alleviates the problem, or by using other native block elements other than span

<kbd>**[Background demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cEDj6/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you make it a div instead of a span it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

This is odd usage of a `span`. Since the semantic element is a `<p>` tag, use that. This also will correct your issue.

Comment: Not really - I actually have a legitimate use of span. In my case, I had a CSS style applied to a few words to apply background color to them. They were spanning two lines as a coincidence, so I noticed this one. I just put a longer block of text to make it more visible here.

Comment: @icyrock.com ah! that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: The other thing to remember when considering using a P vs SPAN for this is that the P is a block element. If your text wraps to a new line for one word, there is still empty space to the right of that word beneath the first part of text the hover will be triggered on because it's still in the P element. The span becomes much more precise in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Funny enough, it's because the span is an inline element and it's wrapping. Because a span is an inline item, and it's wrapping, you get individual lines, and there is space between the lines. I never picked up on this before, but, because you have a mouseout event, it makes it more obvious. To demonstrate this, check out this update on your fiddle.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LSRvn/

```
The reason a DIV doesn't do this is because the DIV is a block element containing the items.
```